# fail to run update-manager.desktop in xubuntu

Tags: updates, xubuntu

my Software Updater fail to run update in xubuntu.
First was Software & Updates failing, did in terminal :

```
software-properties-gtk
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo shutdown -r now

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

and reboot.  And it lost Software Updater too.  Message: "fail to run update-manager.desktop in xubuntu".
May I have a chance to repair, pls  ?

Comment: Did you get any messages when you ran the commands.  We don't know your release, however I'd start with `sudo apt update` (or `sudo apt-get update`) and read the messages looking for any missing lines of output, or any clues. We can't see the output of your commands (unless you provide them), but that's where I'd look for clues.

Comment: already did a install for update-manager and is ok

Comment: Only: jim@jim-Lenovo-IdeaPad-N585:~$ software-properties-gtk
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.96:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3...

Comment: For Software & Update, working on it

Comment: tks for formating

Comment: need the luncher for : software-properties-gtk, pls

Comment: I have python3.8 and python3 in /usr/bin/

Comment: Please add additional details to your question (you can edit your own questions).  We need to know your release details, but if you've changed the default `python3` (or for older releases, `python` & `python3`) you'll find many Ubuntu tools no longer work, esp. those that rely on python; which includes package tools (`dpkg` will work, but not `apt`, `apt-get` etc).  The fix to that is to restore python back to defaults for your release (as I don't know your release, I can't provide what `python -V; python3 -V` should respond, but match it with your release details)

Comment: jim@jim-Lenovo-IdeaPad-N585:~$ apt list software-properties-gtk -a
Listing... Done
software-properties-gtk/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 0.98.9.3 all [installed]
software-properties-gtk/focal-security,focal-security 0.98.9.2 all
software-properties-gtk/focal,focal 0.98.9 all

Comment: jim@jim-Lenovo-IdeaPad-N585:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: Start-Date: 2020-12-15  02:17:15
Commandline: apt upgrade
Upgrade: whoopsie:amd64 (0.2.69ubuntu0.1, 0.2.69ubuntu0.2), gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 (3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.8-0ubuntu1), libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.69ubuntu0.1, 0.2.69ubuntu0.2), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.8.1, 1:0.8.4~0.20.04.3), libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 (3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.8-0ubuntu1), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14), python3-problem-report:amd64 ...

Comment: i think is that upgrade did the wrong...

Comment: And this: Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: jim (1000)
Remove: hplip-data:amd64 (3.20.3+dfsg0-2), python3-olefile:amd64 (0.46-2), libllvm9:amd64 (1:9.0.1-12), printer-driver-postscript-hp:amd64 (3.20.3+dfsg0-2), python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 (3.5.34-1ubuntu1), libgspell-1-common:amd64 (1.8.3-1), python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.1), libimagequant0:amd64 (2.12.2-1.1), python3-renderpm:amd64 (3.5.34-1ubuntu1), libappstream-glib8:amd64 (0.7.16-1ubuntu1), libgspell-1-2:amd64 (1.8.3-1), python3-reportlab:amd64 (3.5.34-1ubuntu1), gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0)

Comment: Please edit & add the additional details to your question.   Also add what you get for `python -V; python3 -V`  ... I saw what looked like `python` errors in your comment, but without the formatting (available on questions & answers) it's hard to read ... and I now suspect isn't your issue.. but it's hard to read *unformatted* pastes

Comment: sorry, i will use format